# Build VS2010 solution on Team Build 2008 - MSTest failed to run

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, mstest, tfsbuild

I have a weird problem while building VS2010 solution incl. unit tests on a Team Build 2008 server. It builds the solution and also can run the test without an error, but after running the test I get following warning which makes the build breaking:

> MSBUILD : warning MSB6003: The
>   specified task executable "MSTest.exe"
>   could not be run. The system cannot
>   find the file specified
>   [C:\data\builds\FSuite\CI_Project[Debug]\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
>   The previous error was converted to a
>   warning because the task was called
>   with ContinueOnError=true.   Build
>   continuing because "ContinueOnError"
>   on the task "TestToolsTask" is set to
>   "true".

It does not seem to be the problem that MSTest have not been found, I also checked if the TFSBuild.proj file is on this localtion -  it is not missing. So what could it be?

Edit:
In meantime I figured out, that our old build server loaded and start the test assemblies once.

> Task "TestToolsTask"   Command:
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe
>   /nologo
>   /runconfig:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Sources\Sources\Products\FSuite.Debug.testrunconfig"
>   /searchpathroot:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug"
>   /resultsfileroot:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\TestResults"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.AppConfiguration.Console.Tests.Unit.dll"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.Common.Tests.Unit.dll"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.Common.UI.Tests.Unit.dll"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.Dbms.Handler.Tests.Unit.dll"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Joint.Base.Tests.Unit.dll"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Joint.BusinessObjects.Tests.Unit.dll"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Joint.Client.Tests.Unit.dll"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Joint.Client.UI.Tests.Unit.dll"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Joint.Enums.Tests.Unit.dll"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Joint.Messages.Tests.Unit.dll"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Joint.Reporting.ReportPackage.Tests.Unit.dll"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Joint.Reporting.Tests.Unit.dll"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.MasterStation.Tests.Unit.dll"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.MonitoringStation.Tests.Unit.dll"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Pac.ProductInspection.Tests.Unit.dll"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Pac.XmlRpcProtocol.Tests.Unit.dll"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Server.DomainLayer.Tests.Unit.dll"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Server.Licensing.Tests.Unit.dll"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Server.NotificationLayer.Tests.Unit.dll"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Tests.Unit.Ext.dll"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Tests.Unit.Joint.dll"
>   /publish:"http://ch06sd01:8080/"
>   /publishbuild:"V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]_20100728.4"
>   /teamproject:"FSuite" /platform:"x86"
>   /flavor:"Debug"     The
>   "TestToolsTask" task is using
>   "MSTest.exe" from "C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe".   Loading C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Sources\Sources\Products\FSuite.Debug.testrunconfig...
>   Loading
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.AppConfiguration.Console.Tests.Unit.dll...
>   Loading
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.Common.Tests.Unit.dll...
>   Loading
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.Common.UI.Tests.Unit.dll...
>   Loading
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.Dbms.Handler.Tests.Unit.dll...
>   Loading
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Joint.Base.Tests.Unit.dll...
>   Loading
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Joint.BusinessObjects.Tests.Unit.dll...
>   Loading
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Joint.Client.Tests.Unit.dll...
>   Loading
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Joint.Client.UI.Tests.Unit.dll...
>   Loading
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Joint.Enums.Tests.Unit.dll...
>   Loading
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Joint.Messages.Tests.Unit.dll...
>   Loading
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Joint.Reporting.ReportPackage.Tests.Unit.dll...
>   Loading
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Joint.Reporting.Tests.Unit.dll...
>   Loading
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.MasterStation.Tests.Unit.dll...
>   Loading
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.MonitoringStation.Tests.Unit.dll...
>   Loading
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Pac.ProductInspection.Tests.Unit.dll...
>   Loading
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Pac.XmlRpcProtocol.Tests.Unit.dll...
>   Loading
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Server.DomainLayer.Tests.Unit.dll...
>   Loading
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Server.Licensing.Tests.Unit.dll...
>   Loading
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Server.NotificationLayer.Tests.Unit.dll...
>   Loading
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Tests.Unit.Ext.dll...
>   Loading
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Tests.Unit.Joint.dll...
>   Starting execution...
>
> Results...
>
> 2387/2387 test(s) Passed
>        Summary   -------   Test Run Warning.
>       Passed  2387
>       ------------
>       Total   2387   Results file:      C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\TestResults\ch06-tfsservice_CH06WL2013302
>   2010-07-28 11_08_03_x86_Debug.trx
>   Run Configuration: FSuite Debug
>   Testconfig
>        Run has the following issue(s):   Code coverage instrumentation warning
>   while processing file
>   MT.FSuite.Joint.Enums.dll:
>   TESTTOOLSTASK : warning VSP2007:
>   C:\data\builds\FSuite\V1.0_CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Joint.Enums.dll
>   contains no instrumentable code.
>   TESTTOOLSTASK : warning : Test Run
>   deployment issue: The assembly or
>   module
>   'DevExpress.RichEdit.v10.1.Core'
>   directly or indirectly referenced by
>   the test container
>   'c:\data\builds\fsuite\v1.0_ci_fsuite[debug]\binaries\x86\debug\mt.fsuite.tests.unit.ext.dll'
>   was not found.   Waiting to publish...
>   Publishing results of test run
>   ch06-tfsservice@CH06WL2013302
>   2010-07-28 11:08:03_x86_Debug to
>   http://ch06sd01:8080/Build/v1.0/PublishTestResultsBuildService2.asmx...
>   ................................Publish
>   completed successfully. Done executing
>   task "TestToolsTask".

But the new build server with VS2010 loads all test assemblies except the MT.FSuite.Tests.Unit.Joint.dll and executes the tests, which run successfully, afterwards MSTest get called again with the mentioned assembly and failes.

> Command:   MSTest.exe /nologo
>   /runconfig:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\CI_FSuite[Debug]\Sources\Sources\Products\FSuite.Debug.testrunconfig"
>   /searchpathroot:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug"
>   /resultsfileroot:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\CI_FSuite[Debug]\TestResults"
>   /testcontainer:"C:\data\builds\FSuite\CI_FSuite[Debug]\Binaries\x86\Debug\MT.FSuite.Tests.Unit.Joint.dll"
>   /publish:"http://ch06sd01:8080/"
>   /publishbuild:"CI_FSuite[Debug]_20100728.2"
>   /teamproject:"FSuite" /platform:"x86"
>   /flavor:"Debug"     The
>   "TestToolsTask" task is using
>   "MSTest.exe" from "MSTest.exe".

I wonder why, because the test container string did not change and furthermore the second time it does not say anymore from where it gets the MSTest.exe...

Thanks for help,
Eny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I've found [the source of the problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsbuild/thread/8d3a253d-f843-469a-b4cb-574c110fa8f9?prof=required). The TeamBuild targets file (C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets) has a wrong value - replace the following:

```
    <UsingTask TaskName="TestToolsTask" 
AssemblyFile="$(MSTestRefPath)\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.MSBuildTasks.dll" 
Condition="'$(ProjectFileVersion)' == '2'" />
```

(the last UsingTask at line 82 if you haven't edited the file already) with:

```
    <UsingTask TaskName="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Tasks.TestToolsTask" 
AssemblyFile="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 
10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.ProcessComponents.dll" 
Condition=" '$(ProjectFileVersion)' == '2' "/>
```

This fixed it for me, and now my build lights are all green.

Comment: We have a second build server with a different failure, this was the answer to solve it ^^ But the first build server still has this weird symptom.